# Change the probability of each branch of a SelectOutput

Tags: anylogic

I am looking to change the probability of each branch of my select output, using an event. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a double variable named `myProb`, set it to the initial probability.

In your `SelectOutput`, use that:
[image]

In your event, change the variable:
[image]

For `SelectOutput5` branches, the approach is the same

Answer (score 1):

create one variable for each probabilty and then in the event you only need to change the variable values.

In the selectOutput or selectOutput5, instead of adding probability 0.3, you will write down variableProbability1 for instance, that will be equal to 0.3